# This IAM user does not have permission to use AWS Config

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Currently, I am exploring the (application) load balancing option in AWS.

I was able to create instances, subnets, target group and application scaling group in a VPC. Each of the instances is accessible through the instance’s *‘Public DNS’*. (i.e., I run a *toy nodejs based program* in port 80 these instances  - and it works fine and accessible through the public DNS url.)

However, when I try to access it through the load balancer, I get the error

> An error occurred while a request was made to AWS Config

However, when I tried to access the AWS Config, I get the error

> This IAM user does not have permission to use AWS Config. Check your
>   IAM user permissions or contact your administrator to get access.

Also, in the *‘Target Group(s)’*, these instances are marked as *‘unhealthy’*. On the other hand, the same instances are marked as *‘healthy’* in the *‘Application Scaling Group’*.

Could this be an IAM user permission issue (i.e., of the account that I am using)?

Comment: The error messages relating to permissions are definitely related to the permissions granted to your IAM user. However, this would not be related to the health checks on the Target Groups.